# Firebase Firestore - how to listen to metadata changes for all documents in collection

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have text views that listen to the number of documents in multiple sub-document collections.

Main Collection
--Doc 1
----Sub Collection
------Doc 1a
------Doc 1b
--Doc 2
----Sub Collection
------Doc 2a
------Doc 2b
------Doc 2c

so, listening to the changes I get;
text1= 2, text2=3

---

In the app I perform a batch write to upload documents into the sub collection and then the listener handles changing the number of docs in collection.
As soon as I commit the batch, the listener is fired and updates the number before its written to Firestore, as noted [here - Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

---

I only want to update the text view AFTER the data is written to Firestore. One way of implementation is somewhat described in that aforementioned page:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("Main Collection")
            .document("Doc 1")
            .collection("Sub Collection")
            .document("Doc 1a")
            .addSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges.INCLUDE) { snapshot, exception ->
                var pending = snapshot!!.metadata.hasPendingWrites()
                //do stuff only when pending == false
            }
```

---

**Questions:** 
 1. Will the above variable 'pending' be changed each time the metadata changes? Have I written this correctly?
 2. My code iterates through each main document and sets a listener for the sub collection doc count. The above snippet only works on a single document and don't want to set multiple listeners for one document. How can I use it to listen to the sub collection doc count AND listen to the meta data changes?
 3. Is there an entirely different and more efficient way of solving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After further testing...

1. Every time the metadata changes, the listener, or at least a portion of it, is fired. so the value of the variable 'pending' will change.
2. When first testing, I must have had some syntax wrong or the ide just spat the dummy... it is now working fine for my collection listeners with that Kotlin syntax.
3. Still unsure if there is a better way, but this is working well currently.